# BDR in secured cluster - Cant get kerberos realm

Tags: kerberos, cloudera-manager

I've Enterprise Cloudera Manager 5.13 managed 2 clusters (Prod and DR). I had tested the Backup and Disaster Recovery (BDR) and it was working fine. Now I've kerberized both servers and installed the sentry service. I've a superuser configured which is in the supergroup with all the permissions (same user on both clusters). I can kinit and klist as well for the superuser on all nodes of the cluster.

Both my clusters are on the same realm, with KDC installed on two servers in master slave configuration.

I've created a new BDR schedule to replicate hive tables from prod to DR. When I dry run it, it fails on "Transfer Metadata Files" with the following error:

```
> Hdfs Copy File Command Failed because of java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get Kerberos realm.
```

What does it even mean that "Can't get Kerberos realm"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to restart the cloudera-manager server and agents. Probably a server restart would have sufficed as well.